# Stats in entity response DTO pageable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to return a DTO response with the entity's statistics pageable.

**Current response:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Customer 1",
        "customerStats": {
            "totalAmount": 950.0,
            "countOrders": 3,
            "countOrdersPending": 1,
            "countOrdersCompleted": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Customer 2",
        "customerStats": {
            "totalAmount": 1867.5,
            "countOrders": 5,
            "countOrdersPending": 2,
            "countOrdersCompleted": 3
        }
    }
]
```

**Expected response:**

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Customer 1",
            "customerStats": {
            "totalAmount": 950.0,
            "countOrders": 3,
            "countOrdersPending": 1,
            "countOrdersCompleted": 2
        }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Customer 2",
            "customerStats": {
            "totalAmount": 1867.5,
            "countOrders": 5,
            "countOrdersPending": 2,
            "countOrdersCompleted": 3
        }
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "empty": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageSize": 20,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "last": true,
    "totalElements": 2,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "empty": true,
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true
    },
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 2,
    "empty": false
}
```

I still need to do the conversion in the controller, how do I do the conversion in the `CustomerController`?

My classes:

**MODEL**

***Customer***

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customers")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

***Order***

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Builder;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "orders")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    public class Order {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_order_customer1"))
        private Customer customer;
        private Double amount;
    
        @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
        private OrderStatusType orderStatus;
    
    }
```

***Enum***

```
public enum OrderStatusType {
    PENDING,
    COMPLETED
}
```

**DTO**

***CustomerStatsDto***

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomerStatsDto {
    private Double totalAmount;
    private Long countOrders;
    private Long countOrdersPending;
    private Long countOrdersCompleted;

    public CustomerStatsDto(Double totalAmount, Long countOrders, Long countOrdersPending, Long countOrdersCompleted) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
        this.countOrders = countOrders;
        this.countOrdersPending = countOrdersPending;
        this.countOrdersCompleted = countOrdersCompleted;
    }
}
```

***CustomerStatsResponse***

```
public interface CustomerStatsResponse {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Double getTotalAmount();
    Long getCountOrders();
    Long getCountOrdersPending();
    Long getCountOrdersCompleted();
}
```

***CustomerStatsResponseDto***

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomerStatsResponseDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private CustomerStatsDto customerStats;

    public CustomerStatsResponseDto(CustomerStatsResponse customerStatsResponse) {
        this.id = customerStatsResponse.getId();
        this.name = customerStatsResponse.getName();
        this.customerStats = new CustomerStatsDto(customerStatsResponse.getTotalAmount(), customerStatsResponse.getCountOrders(),
                customerStatsResponse.getCountOrdersPending(), customerStatsResponse.getCountOrdersCompleted());
    }
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

***OrderRep***

```
import com.example.demo.model.Order;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface OrderRep extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
}
```

***CustomerRep***

```
import com.example.demo.dto.CustomerStatsResponse;
import com.example.demo.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface CustomerRep extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT c.id, c.name, " +
            "SUM(o.amount) AS totalAmount, " +
            "COUNT(o.id) AS countOrders, " +
            "(SELECT COUNT(ord.id) FROM orders ord " +
            "WHERE ord.customer_id = c.id AND ord.order_status = 'PENDING') as countOrdersPending, " +
            "(SELECT COUNT(ord.id) FROM orders ord " +
            "WHERE ord.customer_id = c.id AND ord.order_status = 'COMPLETED') as countOrdersCompleted " +
            "FROM customers c " +
            "INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer_id " +
            "GROUP BY c.id, c.name"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    List<CustomerStatsResponse> customerStats();

    @Query(value = "SELECT c.id, c.name, " +
            "SUM(o.amount) AS totalAmount, " +
            "COUNT(o.id) AS countOrders, " +
            "(SELECT COUNT(ord.id) FROM orders ord " +
            "WHERE ord.customer_id = c.id AND ord.order_status = 'PENDING') as countOrdersPending, " +
            "(SELECT COUNT(ord.id) FROM orders ord " +
            "WHERE ord.customer_id = c.id AND ord.order_status = 'COMPLETED') as countOrdersCompleted " +
            "FROM customers c " +
            "INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer_id " +
            "GROUP BY c.id, c.name"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    Page<CustomerStatsResponse> customerStatsPageable(Pageable pageable);

}
```

**SERVICE**

***CustomerService***

```
import com.example.demo.dto.CustomerStatsResponse;
import com.example.demo.model.Customer;
import com.example.demo.repository.CustomerRep;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerService {

    private final CustomerRep customerRep;

    public List<Customer> findAll() {
        return customerRep.findAll();
    }

    public List<CustomerStatsResponse> customerStats() {
        return customerRep.customerStats();
    }

    public Page<CustomerStatsResponse> customerStatsPageable(Pageable pageable) {
        return customerRep.customerStatsPageable(pageable);
    }

}
```

**CONTROLLER**

***CustomerController***

```
import com.example.demo.dto.CustomerStatsResponseDto;
import com.example.demo.model.Customer;
import com.example.demo.service.CustomerService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerController {

    private final CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/stats")
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomerStatsResponseDto>> customerStats() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.customerStats().stream()
                .map(customerStatsResponse -> new CustomerStatsResponseDto(customerStatsResponse))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    @GetMapping("/stats/pageable")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<CustomerStatsResponseDto>> customerStatsPageable(Pageable pageable) {
        //Return Customer Stats pageable
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do the response conversion in a some other class like helper. Don't do it in the controller. To get page count and other page related stats are available in the page object response. Pick the required attributes from that page object and construct a new model based on your response and return it to controller.

Comment: this time I'm going to use João answer, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with `Page.map()` method ([reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)):

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerController {

    private final CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/stats")
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomerStatsResponseDto>> customerStats() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.customerStats().stream()
                .map(CustomerStatsResponseDto::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    @GetMapping("/stats/pageable")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<CustomerStatsResponseDto>> customerStatsPageable(Pageable pageable) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.customerStatsPageable()
                .map(CustomerStatsResponseDto::new));
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not possible. Are you sure you don't have a `stream()` somewhere? My answer as none in `customerStatsPageable()` method, please check it carefully.